# Hot reload by air is not working on my app

Tags: docker, go

I want to use hot reload in my golang app.
I use [air](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air) package.

But when I modify my `main.go`, the api response is not changed.

↓ my app folders.

```
my-app
   |--- app
   |      |--- .air.toml
   |      |--- Dockerfile
   |      |--- go.mod
   |      |--- go.sum
   |      |--- main.go
   |
   |--- docker-compose.yml
```

↓ Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.16

ENV GOPATH /go
ENV GO111MODULE on

COPY go.mod /var/www/html/go.mod
COPY go.sum /var/www/html/go.sum
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
RUN go mod download

RUN go mod tidy && \
    go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@v1.27.3

COPY . /var/www/html/

CMD ["air", "-c", ".air.toml"]
```

↓ docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: "air"
```

↓ main.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    engine := gin.Default()
    engine.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "message": "hello world",
        })
    })
    engine.Run(":3000")
}
```

I created `.air.toml` by `air init` command in my app container.

And when I do command `docker-compose up --build`, I get ↓.

[my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SKu9.png)

What is wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue. 

If I run Go APP via "air" on my machine, then hot reloading works. 
If I run it on a Docker container with Docker compose, files inside the container get updated, but the reloading is not called. 

Once, I managed to fix it on my old project, by deleting ".air.toml" config file.
Now I have the same problem and I just cannot get passed it.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me without problems. Just changed

Dockerfile

```
   FROM golang:1.18
   ...
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  ...
  #  depends_on:
  #- mysql
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you. But it did not work...
What should I see any other else?